# Reference shared libraries using relative paths or library names on OS X?

Tags: macos, shared-libraries

It seems that shared libraries on OS X are referenced as absolute paths:

```
$ otool -L /bin/ls
/bin/ls:
    /usr/lib/libutil.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib (compatibility version 5.4.0, current version 5.4.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
```

While on Linux, libraries are mostly referenced as their names. Can I change this behavior?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: I checked FreeBSD, which works the same way as Linux. I wonder whether it's only a matter of linker, but after I used gcc (not clang) on OS X, it didn't change anything.

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm facing a similar problem right now.

Comment: @IneQuation No, still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix these paths up using the `install_name_tool`. It's preferred to do it on the shared library with the `-id` option, but you could also just fix up the executable using `-change`. Consult `man install_name_tool` for details.

I change the install name on the shared library to `@loader_path/libfoo.1.2.3.dylib` and redistribute `libfoo.1.2.3.dylib` with the executable. If you search the web for `rpath executable_path loader_path` you'll find documentation on what those `@paths` are.